# intellij community 2016.2 jboss integration plugin not found

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, server, integration

I have IntelliJ community version 2016.2 and I want to enable The JBoss Integration plugin but in settings/repository, but there is no the JBoss Integration Plugin found. IntelliJ cannot find it in repository and on the website repository I can't find this plugin also. How to install and enable it? IntelliJ does not see JBoss Seam components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The JBoss, Tomcat and most other application server plugins are only available in the Ultimate Edition. See the **Deployment** section [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Comment: A way back to Eclipse :(

Answer (score 1):

Go **File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse Repositories**

and enter **jboss**

and You can find both **JBoss Forge Idea plugin** and **JBoss JBPM**.
Both of them **support Community Edition**.

On Mac you need to go to IntelliJ IDEA->Preferences->Plugins->Browse Repositories. Also, JBoss JBPM is not compatible with Community Edition.

Comment: I have those plugins but there are not the JBoss integration plugin. I think it is only in Ultimate edition.

Comment: Can one of those plugins be used for deployment (to JBoss EAP)?